# Font Awesome SVG and text alignment

Tags: font-awesome

I'm trying to align text horizontally in line with Font Awesome SVG animation as per the image[image: alignment]

What I can't get round is the placing of the text as per the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/4wvbrp6o/8/

```
<div class="gears">
<i class="fas fa-cog fa-5x slow-spin" data-fa-transform="down-6  right-5"></i>
<i class="fas fa-cog fa-4x slow-spin" data-fa-transform="down-19 right-1"></i>
<i class="fas fa-cog fa-6x slow-spin" data-fa-transform="up-1 left-9"></i>
  <h1>
  TO BE ALIGNED IN LINE
  </h1>
</div>

.slow-spin {
  -webkit-animation: fa-spin 6s infinite linear;
  animation: fa-spin 6s infinite linear;
}

h1{
  font-size: 36px;
}
```

As soon as I style the text as h1 the alignment goes off completely. How can I align the text as per the image?

Comment: `h1` is `display:block` by default. Set it to `display:inline`? Also, your gears are grinding, please reverse the middle one :P